# How to use bash parameter substitution to remove "./"?

Tags: bash, substitution

I am writing a bash script to change a string

```
./FirstJavaProgram.class
```

to

```
FirstJavaProgram
```

I came up with this script. However bash complains line 4 is bad substitution.

```
#!/bin/sh
file=${1%%.class}
echo $file
file=${file/.\//}
```

How should I write the correct syntax?

Comment: `file="${file/.\//}"` You can prove it to yourself with `file="./FirstJavaProgram.class"; echo "${file/.\//}"`  (note: since you are not replacing with anything, `"${file/.\/}"` -- the closing `'/'` is presumed) Also in bash `file="${file:2}"` will do it as well.

Comment: You can also use `"${file#*/}"` If your string is outside the script, you don't need a script at all, e.g. `echo "./FirstJavaProgram.class" | sed 's|^[.]/||'`

Comment: @drdot : `basename "$file" .class`

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` does not run your script with **bash**. `sh` is a different language, with fewer features (including, less available PE syntax). Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to use a copy of bash found with a PATH lookup, or `#!/bin/bash` to use a copy of bash from `/bin` if you're sure that's the one you want.

Comment: @user1934428, ...starting the external program `basename` is a lot slower to run than the built-into-the-shell PE approach the OP asked for. Compare `time for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do file=$(basename "$file" .class); done` with `time for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do file=${file##*/}; file=${file%.class}; done`. I measure 100 `basename`s as taking more than half a second, whereas the PE loop finishes in under 1/100th of a second total.

Comment: One way, quick, simple but not the safest (...) , is simply to copy a launcher script, or even the script itself in `/usr/bin`, while taking good care of dependencies paths. I do this since years, not a problem to me. By doing so, you can then call your programs from other script and build complex stuffs.

Comment: @drdot, ...and in the future, use the `sh` tag for questions about `#!/bin/sh` scripts; the bash tag should only be used for bash scripts.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Your solution just removes the path prefix, but not the extension `.class`.

Comment: @user1934428 `echo "./FirstJavaProgram.class" | sed -e 's|^[.]/||' -e 's/[.].*$//'`

Answer (score 1):

`${var//search/replace}` is a **bash**-only feature. It is not guaranteed to be present with `/bin/sh`. Use `${var#prefix}` instead, which is part of the POSIX sh specification and so guaranteed to be offered by `/bin/sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
file=${1%.class}
echo "Trimmed suffix:      $file"
file=${file#./}
echo "Also trimmed prefix: $file"
```

...if the parameter is `./FirstJavaProgram.class`, the output will be:

```
Trimmed suffix:      ./FirstJavaProgram
Also trimmed prefix: FirstJavaProgram
```

By contrast, if you want to use bash-only features, start your script with `#!/usr/bin/bash`, or `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, etc. as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:
`echo "./FirstJavaProgram.class" | sed 's\[.]/\\'`

Your script should be look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=./FirstJavaProgram.class
echo $file 
echo $file | sed 's\[.]/\\'
```

Comment: When a question asks for a PE (which is fast and efficient, requiring no tools outside of bash itself), answering with `sed` (an external binary that takes time to start up) is not ideal.

Comment: (Also, this has the bugs discussed in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else))